# how to get max values in dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
text = 'orange strawberry barley gooseberry apple apricot barley currant orange melon pomegranate banana banana orange barley apricot plum grapefruit banana quince strawberry barley grapefruit banana grapes melon strawberry apricot currant currant gooseberry raspberry apricot currant orange lime quince grapefruit barley banana melon pomegranate barley banana orange barley apricot plum banana quince lime grapefruit strawberry gooseberry apple barley apricot currant orange melon pomegranate banana banana orange apricot barley plum banana grapefruit banana quince currant orange melon pomegranate barley plum banana quince barley lime grapefruit pomegranate barley'

slowar = {}

list = text.split(' ')

for word in list:

    if word not in slowar:

        slowar[word] = 1

    else:

        slowar[word] += 1


max(slowar.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your question and provide more details on what the expected output is.

Comment: What's wrong with yours?

Comment: please edit your question it's unclear what you want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

```
max(slowar,  key=slowar.get)
```

is what you need.